# ORACLE : Not able to open employee table in system schema in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

When i enter SELECT * FROM Emp;

It is showing ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I have done so many things and not able to unlock it . 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the Employees table? And if you did, did you commit? Does your user have enough privileges to access the table?

Comment: DDL commits in Oracle, no need to explicitly commit a `create table` statement (and you can't rollback).

Comment: I think it is a default table in ORACLE Emp

Comment: I do not recall having a default EMP table in ORACLE. When I studied it, we had to create the EMP table from SQL script.

Comment: Thank  you so much MAT and OMAR

Answer (score -1):

employees table exist in HR user first you have to unlock HR user.